# problem with custom form handler in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to create a custom hook that'll can be used in any form but i have a problem which i am not sure of what it is. whenever i start typing into the fields it loses focus, to type into it again you'd have to click into it and it goes on like that. this isn't good and i would appreciate it if anyone can help me solve this error.

**useForm.js**

```
import { useState } from "react";

const useForm = () => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    //   contact form
  });
  const [errors, seterrors] = useState({});

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setValues({
      ...values,
      [name]: value
    });
    // console.log(name, value);
  };

  const validate = (data) => {};

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // console.log(e);
  };
  //   console.log(values);

  return {
    handleChange,
    values,
    handleSubmit
  };
};

export default useForm;
```

**Form.js**

```
import InputGroup from "./InputGroup";
import useForm from "./useForm";
const Form = () => {
  const fields = [
    {
      label: "First Name",
      className: "input-group",
      name: "firstName",
      placeholder: "John",
      type: "text"
    },
    {
      label: "Last Name",
      className: "input-group",
      name: "lastName",
      placeholder: "Doe",
      type: "text"
    },
    {
      label: "Email",
      className: "input-group",
      name: "email",
      placeholder: "JohnDoe@example.com",
      type: "email"
    },
    {
      label: "Phone Number",
      className: "input-group",
      name: "Phone",
      placeholder: "+234 (0)81 234 5678",
      type: "text"
      // pattern: "/^[+]*[(]{0,1}[0-9]{1,4}[)]{0,1}[-s./0-9]*$/g"
    },
    {
      label: "Comments",
      className: "input-group",
      name: "comment",
      placeholder: "Message",
      type: "textarea"
    }
  ];

  const { values, handleChange, handleSubmit } = useForm();
  //funtion to generate id based on fields lenght
  const id = () => {
    const head = Date.now.toString(36);
    const tail = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2);

    return head + tail;
  };
  console.log(id);

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      {fields.map((field) => (
        <InputGroup
          key={id}
          value={values}
          onChange={handleChange}
          {...field}
        />
      ))}
      <button>submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

**Input**

```
const Input = ({ ...props }) => {
  return <input {...props} />;
};

export default Input;
```

Comment: where is `InputGroup`?

Comment: The problem is your use of `key`, and there is more than one problem with it. Currently all elements share the same key: the function instance you named `id`. And this instance is created new on every render. When you type one letter the component renders again and your id function will be a different instance. You could just use the `name` of each field as the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using your `id` function properly, you are only referring to it, not invoking it, change -

```
<InputGroup
          key={id}
```

to

```
<InputGroup
          key={id()}
```

or better still, a better name, using a verb would have highlighted the problem easier, as it now looks like a function and not a variable

```
<InputGroup
          key={buildId()}
```

or whatever, but better still, you should use a *static* unique value for the key (i.e unique but would not change between renders, so using timestamps is a bad idea), so you could add a unique id to each `field` and use it -

```
const fields = [
    {
      id: <some unique ID>,  <!---- here
      label: "First Name",
      className: "input-group",
      name: "firstName",
      placeholder: "John",
      type: "text"
    }
    ...
]

...

<InputGroup
          key={field.id}
```